# Difference between checkout remote branch and pull remote branch in git?

Tags: git, merge, git-pull, git-checkout

What is the difference between:

```
git checkout -b <branch> origin/<branch>
```

and

```
git pull origin <branch>
```

They seem to have the same functionality to me.  thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`git pull` contacts the remote repository identified by `origin` and looks for updates.  It fetches any updates and then merges the changes into the target branch. It *does not* create a new branch.

`git checkout -b <branch> origin/<branch>` *creates a new branch* based on `origin/<branch>`, and does not contact the remote repository.  It looks at `origin/<branch>` as it currently exists in your local repository.

The two commands perform very different actions; spending some quality time with the `git-pull` and `git-checkout` man pages might help clarify things.

Comment: If we use `git checkout origin/<branch>` does it update the local repository ?

Comment: It does not pull changes from the remote repository, if that is what you're asking.  If you have more questions you may want to post a new question here on StackOverflow.

Comment: So what does it exactly ?